# Insert bulk data in sql server while ignoring/capturing duplicate rows

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have an excel file with rows between 8000 - 10000. I am converting it to an xml in c# and passing it to the stored procedure to insert it in to the table.

While inserting the data if there is an entry that already exist in the database I want to ignore/capture it while inserting rest of the rows without breaking the insertion.

One of the solutions that I think is to create a insert trigger on the table to check whether the row already exists in the table or not but this approach is very costly for 10,000 rows.

What else could be the way? Below is the short hand code

```
 SELECT @sql = N'
    INSERT INTO Expenses ( '+ STUFF(@col,1,1,'') +')
    SELECT ' + STUFF(@col,1,1,'') + '
    FROM #TEMPTABLE t
    PIVOT (
        MAX([Value]) FOR AttributeName IN (' + STUFF(@col,1,1,'')+')
    ) as pvt'

    EXEC ( @sql )
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are only concerned about duplicate entries already in the table, you can do something like this:

```
with p as (<your pivot here>)
    insert into Expenses ( . . . )
        select p.*
        from p
        where not exists (select 1
                          from Expenses e
                          where e.entry = p.entry
                         );
```

This works okay for your specific case -- finding entries that are already in the table and avoiding them.  However, it will not remove duplicates within the temporary table.  Also, it does not combine data already in `Expenses` with the new data.

I am guessing that you really want `merge`.  If the above doesn't fix your problem, then ask *another* question.  This question does not provide enough information to explain what the `merge` solution would look like.  The other question would have sample data and desired results.

Comment: I am fine with not removing duplicate data from the temp table. All i want is to capture the duplicate data separately somewhere to pass it back to the user. Your solution could help me inserting non-duplicate data but how can I store the duplicate rows?

Comment: @user728630 . . . Your question is "I want to ignore", which is what this does.  If you want to do something else, then write a query that finds the duplicate rows and return them . . . as a separate step.